# Could not build Objective-C module 'CoreGraphics'

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, cocoapods, leveldb

I'm getting the following error when trying to run any of my unit or UI tests. Doesn't happen when running the application itself. The error message is shown below:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CGBase.h:12:10: note: while building module 'CoreFoundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CGBase.h:12:
#include <CoreFoundation/CFBase.h>
     ^
<module-includes>:1:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:1:
#import "Headers/CoreFoundation.h"
    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:43:10: note: in file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:43:
#include <CoreFoundation/CFBase.h>
     ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFBase.h:72:10: note: in file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CFBase.h:72:
#include <Block.h>
     ^
/Users/eirik/Documents/Utvikling/iOS/ProsjekterSamarbeid/AnchorPoint Fishing as/FerskFiskiOS/Pods/leveldb-library/table/Block.h:10:10: note: in file included from /Users/eirik/Documents/Utvikling/iOS/ProsjekterSamarbeid/AnchorPoint Fishing as/FerskFiskiOS/Pods/leveldb-library/table/Block.h:10:
#include "leveldb/iterator.h"
     ^
/Users/eirik/Documents/Utvikling/iOS/ProsjekterSamarbeid/AnchorPoint Fishing as/FerskFiskiOS/Pods/leveldb-library/include/leveldb/iterator.h:18:10: note: in file included from /Users/eirik/Documents/Utvikling/iOS/ProsjekterSamarbeid/AnchorPoint Fishing as/FerskFiskiOS/Pods/leveldb-library/include/leveldb/iterator.h:18:
#include "leveldb/slice.h"

/Users/eirik/Documents/Utvikling/iOS/ProsjekterSamarbeid/AnchorPoint Fishing as/FerskFiskiOS/Pods/leveldb-library/include/leveldb/slice.h:21:10: error: 'string' file not found
#include <string>
     ^
<module-includes>:1:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:1:
#import "Headers/CoreGraphics.h"
    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CoreGraphics.h:8:10: note: in file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CoreGraphics.h:8:
#include <CoreGraphics/CGBase.h>
     ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator11.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Headers/CGBase.h:12:10: error: could not build module 'CoreFoundation'
#include <CoreFoundation/CFBase.h>
     ^
<unknown>:0: error: could not build Objective-C module 'CoreGraphics'
```

I'm using Xcode 9 in Swift 3.2 mode and CocoaPods. I'm using Firebase and FirebaseUI, which has `leveldb` as a dependency. You can see that the error is first triggered in `leveldb/slice.h`, which cannot find the `string` file.

I have tried the following up to this point:

- Clean (Shift + CMD + K)
- Remove DerivedData
- Clean Build Folder...
- Allow Non-Modular Includes In Framework Modules in Build Settings.
- `pod deintegrate`, `pod clean` `pod install`.

For what it's worth, here's the error in the Issue Navigator:
[image: Error in Issue Navigator]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue? I am having the same problem.

Comment: Did you see the comment I made under the answer about it working and that one should set `Enable Bitcode` to `NO`? I that's not working for you, then I can't help, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks similar to a [CocoaPods issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/7006) that was fixed in CocoaPods 1.4.0. Search paths were not properly set for unit test targets.

Try updating to the CocoaPods 1.4.0 beta and rerun `pod update`

***Or*** use a comparable workaround to the one described [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/58) for the leveldb path:

Add `"${PODS_ROOT}/leveldb-library/include"` to your Tests target only under `Build Settings -> Header Search Paths`

Comment: I ran `pod update`, and then the *Could not build Objective-C module 'CoreGraphics* error went away, but now I'm presented with the following error: *Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) note: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64*.

Comment: Thank you, it's now working as expected! For anyone getting the error I mentioned in my last comment, set `Enable Bitcode` to `NO`.

Comment: I tried the workaround suggested and it didn't fix anything. I also tried updating to CocoaPods 1.4.0 beta 2 and I'm getting ```lipo: -remove's specified would result in an empty fat file``` instead. Any help would be appreciated.

Environment: Xcode 9.1 using Swift 3.2.