# Cannot build Capacitor App with FirebaseMessaging on latest iPhoneOS16.0.2

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase-cloud-messaging, cocoapods, capacitor

I have a capacitor cpp with a iOS platform. It uses Firebase Messaging to receive push notifications. I am on the latest version of everything. iPhoneOS16.0.2, Firebase/Messaging@9.6.0. I get the following errors when building the app:

[image]

one of the errors is

```
Could not build module 'CoreGraphics'

While building module 'Foundation' imported from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS16.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Accessibility.framework/Headers/AXFoundation.h:11:
```

to me it seems like the sdk does not work with the current FirebaseMessages Pod?

I also tried out alle the common ways to get rid of those errors.

I [removed all caches](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/128535), I removed the pods and reinstalled, I updated all pods, I updated CocoaPods, [I removed the DerivedData folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46871673/could-not-build-objective-c-module-coregraphics) and so on (2h of removing and reinstalling things).

I used that tutorial to make everything work: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YUr8pw0nO7Y

By the way my android build works like charm .

I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Which Capacitor Plugin do you use?

Comment: I use "@capacitor/push-notifications": "^4.1.0"

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?

Comment: Yes, I completely deleted the platform and added it again.